# How to calculate confidence interval for option price?

Tags: options, option-pricing, statistics

I model option prices for European call using Monte Carlo method. **What is the proper way to calculate the confidence interval?**

**A.** 
-> Calculate the payoffs (there will be number of zeros as some prices go below strike) 
-> calculate mean and st.dev. of the payoffs 
-> apply the formula for the confidence interval:   **mean option payoff +/- z*(st.dev option payoff / sqrt(number of simulation) )**  
-> discount

or  
 
**B.** 
-> Calculate the mean and st.dev. of all the prices at maturity 
-> apply the formula for the confidence interval:   **mean underlying priceT +/- z*(st.dev underlying priceT / sqrt(number of simulation) )**  
->  calculate upper and lower band of the payoffs  
->  discount

where payoff is max(underlying asset priceT - option strike price,0)

Comment: What is the difference between "price at maturity" and "payoff"? I.e. between approach A and B?

Comment: under PriceT I meant the price of underlying asset at T, under payoff the payment from exercising the option  max(St-K,0) where K is the strike price of the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is approach A. Approach B does not work because of the [Jensen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality). Take note that your confidence intervals are only asymptotically correct. Depending on the number of scenarios, your options and their parameters these might provide bad coverage.